# How can I duplicate a gridview's header?

Tags: asp.net, sorting, gridview

I want to have to duplicate a gridview's header row after each 25 "normal" rows.
I'd like to save option to sort the grid by clicking on these columns.
Is it possible?

Comment: What is your DataSource of Gridview?

Comment: @Muhammad Akhtar: What do you exactly mean by datasource of gridview? I'm using objectdatasource

Comment: did you try to set property of gridview AllowSorting="true", if you have use ObjectDataSource as DataSource, you don't need to be worry about sorting, it will handle automatically

Comment: @Muhammad Akhtar: sure, but the question is following: I want to duplicate the gridview's header row after each 25 rows.

Answer (score 1):

Set `AllowSorting="true"`, if your gridview has SQLDataSource/ObjectDataSource.

and you need to set `SortExpression="FieldName"` to your columns

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="" HeaderText="" SortExpression="FieldName" />
```